# C++ vector manipulation optimization

Tags: c++, vector

I'm trying to optimize the following code below to avoid having to copy and paste and just use SlaveForce and SlavePos properly, which are float[6] type, and baseForce and basePos are vector type:

```
typedef struct _NodeCoord
{
    float coords[6];
} NodeCoord;

int main()
{
    ...
    memcpy(tempNodeCoord.coords, SlaveForce, 6*sizeof(float));
    baseForce.push_back(tempNodeCoord);
    memcpy(tempNodeCoord.coords, SlavePos, 6*sizeof(float));
    basePos.push_back(tempNodeCoord);
    ...
}
```

I have tried some test codes. Only this appear to work:

```
std::vector<NodeCoord> tallon;
NodeCoord m;
memset(m.coords, 0, sizeof(m.coords));
tallon.push_back(m);
```

while this is along the lines of what I want to accomplish, but it doesn't work:

```
std::vector<float[6]> ed;
float e[6];
tallon.push_back(e);
```

I also tried writing a "typedef float[6] mytype;" line before the main function, but it doesn't work well either. Is there anything that I can do to eliminate the memcpy function calls (or rather push_back the float[6] variables directly)? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to be storable in a vector, a type must be copyable and assignable, and C-style arrays are neither. You should instead use another vector, or possibly wrap the array in a struct.

Comment: What would be the difference between using another vector and wrapping the array in a struct (which is what I'm doing already)?

Comment: The wrapped array will probably be faster, but less flexible - for erxample, you can't find how many things are actually in an array.

Comment: Can't I use sizeof(array)/sizeof(element) to find out how many elements are in the array?

Comment: There are a lot of circumstances where that simply won't work. And if it does it only tells you the size of the array, not how many actual values it contains.

Comment: In terms of cleanliness, does the the first method provide better readability?

Comment: Youb should always prefer to use vectors rather than arrays as the first-order solution - the code will be much cleaner and more readable. However, an array wrapped in a struct can easily be turned into a fairly well-defined class, so it is another viable solution. These trade-offs are things that only experience can teach, I'm afraid - there is no "right" answer.

Comment: You could use structures such as tvmet::Vector [http://tvmet.sourceforge.net/] or vnl_vector_fixed [http://public.kitware.com/vxl/doc/release/core/vnl/html/index.html], they are very nice abstractions for C++ small arrays of numbers!

Comment: ... and what is important: gaining abstraction without losing any performance!

Answer (score 2):

Try a vector of vectors:

```
std::vector<std::vector<float> > ed;

ed.push_back(std::vector<float>(6, 0.0f));
```

In this case I'm pushing a temp vector of floats, with 6 elements with the value of 0.0f;

[Info on vector's constructors](http://www.cppreference.com/wiki/stl/vector/vector_constructors).

Answer (score 2):

This is c++, why not try a class?

```
class NodeCoord { 
public:
    float coords[6];
    NodeCoord() {memset(coords, 0, sizeof(coords));};
    ~NodeCoord() {};
};

std::vector<NodeCoord> tallon;
tallon.push_back(NodeCoord());

cout << tallon.front().coords[0];
```

And you can do a lot more with the class, if you choose. If you wish to avoid copies, just make shallow copies of the class in a copy constructor.